# Is there a way to decode APK files in Android Studio to recover a project file?

Tags: android-studio, apk

I lost my Android Studio project; I deleted it by mistake.

I still have the apk file; is there any chance that I can get my project back using this file somehow?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. You can search for 'apk decompiler', but the result will be poor, I'm afraid. Start using version control and backups.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be possible to generate the project back from APK file. You can do reverse engineering to get the code back but its not 100% useful.

Comment: I will try it thanx